# Error in the simple Tensorflow code in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn, librosa

I have a deep learning code written in python (Anaconda3, Ubuntu 16.04). It basically does ad detection for a given video based on a trained model, must return if the video is ad or not (we assume it is only a single-shot video). My colleague who is unavailable right now wrote this.

The original file had a loop somewhere (for multiple shot) iterating over the list of the shots, and now that loop is removed assuming the video is a single shot. But looks some array sizes are messed up, hence the error. How to fix the problem?

I'm not familiar with python and deep learning, and it should be general python programming issues, not the semantics because it worked fine just before.

Here is the error:

```
 File "/Ad_module_textfast_stream.py", line 36, in label_prediction
    pred_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_feat.reshape(-1, 200) )
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8640 into shape (200)
```

So it should run when calling `video_audio_extractor(video_name)`. Here is the code. Right now `final_label_list` must contain if it is video or ad. And I guess since it is only a single shot, it must contain only one element.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import time, cv2, librosa
import skvideo.io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import subprocess, os, glob
from sklearn.externals import joblib



#################################### Loading the Dataset
def label_prediction( mfcc_list, num_frames= 3):

    num_shots= len(mfcc_list)
    pred_labels_list= list()
    final_label_list= list()


    if 2>1:
        clf_trained = joblib.load('trainsvm_mfcc.pkl') 
        #predicted_train_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_list)   

        for j in range(num_shots):
            mfcc_feat = mfcc_list[j]     
            num_frames= 1
            mfcc_feat= ( mfcc_feat- np.mean(mfcc_feat) ) / ( np.std(mfcc_feat)+ 1e-6 )
    #### now access operation you wanna run

            #pred_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_feat)
            pred_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_feat.reshape(-1, 200) )

            final_label= 0  ## ads:1, and video:0
            if pred_labels> 0:
                final_label= 1

            pred_labels_list.append(pred_labels)
            final_label_list.append(final_label)

    ################ post-processing
    final_label_list[0]= 0 ### video starts with natural content
    final_label_list[len(final_label_list)-1]= 0 ## last  shot
    for kk in range(2,len(final_label_list)-2): ### one video between many ads, most likely to be ads
        if final_label_list[kk]==0 and final_label_list[kk-2]==1 and final_label_list[kk-1]==1 and final_label_list[kk+1]==1 and final_label_list[kk+2]==1:
            final_label_list[kk]= 1

    return final_label_list, pred_labels_list


def video_audio_extractor( video_name):
    cur_video= skvideo.io.vread(video_name)
    metadata = skvideo.io.ffprobe(video_name)
    vid_info= metadata["video"]
    items = list(vid_info.items())
    avg_fps_info= items[22][1]
    avg_fps= int(avg_fps_info[0:2])

    cur_num_frame= cur_video.shape[0]
    cur_audio, cur_sr= librosa.load(video_name)

    mfcc_list= list()
    cur_audioshot_mfcc= librosa.feature.mfcc( y= cur_audio, sr= cur_sr, n_mfcc=20)
    cur_audioshot_mfcc_1d= np.reshape( cur_audioshot_mfcc, [cur_audioshot_mfcc.shape[0]*cur_audioshot_mfcc.shape[1],])
    mfcc_list.append(cur_audioshot_mfcc_1d)
    final_label_list, pred_labels_list= label_prediction( mfcc_list, num_frames= 3)

    return mfcc_list, avg_fps, final_label_list
```

Below is the original `video_audio_extractor` function for which contains the for loop:

```
def video_audio_extractor( video_name):
    cur_video= skvideo.io.vread(video_name)
    metadata = skvideo.io.ffprobe(video_name)
    vid_info= metadata["video"]
    items = list(vid_info.items())
    avg_fps_info= items[22][1]
    avg_fps= int(avg_fps_info[0:2])

    cur_num_frame= cur_video.shape[0]
    cur_audio, cur_sr= librosa.load(video_name)
    cur_shot_name= 'video_shots.txt'

    #cur_shot_name= cur_video_name[0:-4]+'_shots.txt'
    line = list(open(cur_shot_name, 'r'))

    mfcc_list= list()
    for shot_ind in range(len(line)):

        cur_line= line[ shot_ind]
        cur_line_list= cur_line.split()
        first_frame= int( cur_line_list[0] )
        last_frame = int( cur_line_list[1] )

        cur_audioshot_first_ind= int( np.floor(first_frame*len(cur_audio)/cur_num_frame ) )
        cur_audioshot_last_ind = int( np.floor(last_frame *len(cur_audio)/cur_num_frame ) )
        cur_audioshot= cur_audio[cur_audioshot_first_ind:cur_audioshot_last_ind]
        new_rate= 5000*cur_sr/len(cur_audioshot)
        cur_audioshot_resampled = librosa.resample(cur_audioshot, cur_sr, new_rate)
        cur_audioshot_mfcc= librosa.feature.mfcc(y=cur_audioshot_resampled, sr= new_rate, n_mfcc=20)
        cur_audioshot_mfcc_1d= np.reshape( cur_audioshot_mfcc, [cur_audioshot_mfcc.shape[0]*cur_audioshot_mfcc.shape[1],])
        mfcc_list.append(cur_audioshot_mfcc_1d)
    return mfcc_list, line, avg_fps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your old `video_audio_extractor` code changes the sampling rate and resamples the audio. Here's the code:

```
new_rate= 5000*cur_sr/len(cur_audioshot)
cur_audioshot_resampled = librosa.resample(cur_audioshot, cur_sr, new_rate)
cur_audioshot_mfcc= librosa.feature.mfcc(y=cur_audioshot_resampled, sr= new_rate, n_mfcc=20)
```

Your new `video_audio_extractor` doesn't use this new rate or do any resampling. That's why the new shape of `mfcc_feat` is different than the old shape of `mfcc_feat`. What happens if you replace the following line:

```
pred_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_feat.reshape(-1, 200) )
```

with this line:

```
pred_labels= clf_trained.predict( mfcc_feat )
```

Comment: So maybe I should copy back those 3 lines? With `(mfcc_feat)` alone I get another error: http://text-share.com/view/86fde0f4

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. You need `cur_audioshot` to compute `cur_audioshot_resampled`, and the new function doesn't compute that variable. I don't know anything about librosa, so I can't help you further.

Comment: And when I add the resample lines, I get this error again:  `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: The code works now! I just added those lines, and I am kinda sure I didn't do anything else. But it works. The problem is that now it always outputs 0 (i.e. ad)!!